# c++ can't insert values in vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, vector

ok i when it try to insert two values in two different vectors it won't work the first one will work but the second won't be setted.

```
   // Xstrike.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Xstrike.h"
#include <vector>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
RECT *rect;
const UINT_PTR EVERYTHING_ID=0x1;
const UINT_PTR LBUTTONDOWN_ID=0x3;
const UINT_PTR TDENEMIE1_ID=0x4;
const UINT_PTR TAENEMIE1_ID=0x5;
int conno=2;
int side=0;
int cEnemie1=0;
int dEnemie1=1;
int aEnemie1=0;
int sEnemie1=1;
bool e1=true;
time_t now;
time_t tEnemie1;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

vector <POINT> vRegularShots;
vector <POINT> vS1Enemie1;
vector <POINT> vS2Enemie1;
VOID Paint(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC memDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hMemMap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 225, 350);
    HBITMAP hOldMap=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemMap);
    Graphics draw(memDC);

    // Drawing
    Image bg(L"bg.jpg");
    draw.DrawImage(&bg, 0, 0);

    // Regular shots
    Image shot(L"RegularShots.png");
    long s=vRegularShots.size();

    // Draw shots
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
    { 
        draw.DrawImage(&shot, vRegularShots[index].x, vRegularShots[index].y);
    }

    // Update the shots
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
    { 
        vRegularShots[index].y--;
    }

    // Create Enemies
    if(dEnemie1==0)
    {
        if(cEnemie1<2)
        {
            if(aEnemie1==0)
            {
                SetTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
            }
            aEnemie1=1;
            cEnemie1++;
        }
        else
        {
            KillTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID);
        }
        dEnemie1=1;
    }

    // Draw enemies
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vS1Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
    {
        Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
        draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, vS1Enemie1[index].x, vS1Enemie1[index].y);
    }
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vS2Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
    {
        Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
        draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, vS2Enemie1[index].x, vS2Enemie1[index].y);
    }

    // Update enemies
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
    {
        vS1Enemie1[index].x++;
        vS1Enemie1[index].y++;
    }
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
    {
        vS2Enemie1[index].x--;
        vS2Enemie1[index].y++;
    }

    // Delete enemies
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
    {
        if(vS1Enemie1[index].x>225)
        {
            vS1Enemie1.erase(vS1Enemie1.begin()+index);
        }
    }
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
    {
        if(vS2Enemie1[index].x>225)
        {
            vS2Enemie1.erase(vS2Enemie1.begin()+index);
        }
    }

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 225, 350, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    SelectObject(memDC, hOldMap);
    DeleteObject(hMemMap);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
}

VOID CheckDead()
{
    for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
    { 
         vRegularShots[index].x, vRegularShots[index].y;
    }
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;
    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);


    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_XSTRIKE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_XSTRIKE));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_XSTRIKE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR));
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_XSTRIKE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX),
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 225, 350, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    POINT pt;
    POINT pts;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hWnd, EVERYTHING_ID, 1, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Paint(hdc, hWnd);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
        if(conno==1)
        {
            conno++;
        }
        else
        {
            pt.x+=18;
            conno--;
        }
        vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
        SetTimer(hWnd, LBUTTONDOWN_ID, 350, NULL); 
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        KillTimer(hWnd, LBUTTONDOWN_ID);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case EVERYTHING_ID:
            if(e1==true)
            {
                now=time(NULL);
                tEnemie1=now+1;
                e1=false;
            }
            now=time(NULL);
            if(now==tEnemie1)
            {
                SetTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case LBUTTONDOWN_ID:
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
            if(conno==1)
            {
                conno++;
            }
            else
            {
                pt.x+=18;
                conno--;
            }
            vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
            break;
        case TDENEMIE1_ID:
            pt.y=5;
            pt.x=-26;
            vS1Enemie1.push_back(pt);
            pt.y=52;
            pt.x=251;
            vS2Enemie1.push_back(pt);
            dEnemie1=0;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case TAENEMIE1_ID:
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

the values in will be inserted in  vS1Enemie1 but not in  vS2Enemie1.
any idea?

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of pt and the definition of pt's type? and also the declaration of the 2 vectors?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the portion of code that you posted. Please post a small, representative, compileable example so you can point to it and say "This is what I expect to see, but here's what happens instead".

Comment: @George take a look, i updated the post

Comment: @Ramiz Toma:  So what is a POINT, and how is it defined?  Are you sure the problem is specifically here, and not some sort of memory corruption?  If you just post perfectly correct code and ask why it's misbehaving, you're not going to get a useful answer.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another case statement in your code where you are just inserting values to vS1Enemie1 & that is the one being executed?

Comment: i put some break points to debug my code and i found that valuses get inserted in  vS1Enemie1 but not in  vS2Enemie1.

Comment: ill but the full code in one second

Comment: This is going to sound silly but I'll ask anyway. Where exactly is your breakpoint? Is it on the line "vS2Enemie1.push_back(pt);" ? If so, you need to step  to the next line before you'll see your new element in the vs2Enemie1 vector.

Comment: omg that was the problem

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: That was your problem? OK, I'll post that as a real answer, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a breakpoint on a particular line of code in visual studio and then hit that breakpoint, then line of code where you put the breakpoint hasn't actually executed yet.

For example, let's let the "*" represent where you've placed your breakpoint in visual studio.

```
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  a = 3;
* b = 4;
```

When you hit the breakpoint, it is after a and b were declared, and after a has been set to 3, but BEFORE the line "b = 4;" has had a chance to execute. Most debuggers do this so you have the opportunity to step into the line of code you put your breakpoint on. For example, I might have had "myComplicatedFunction(a, b);" instead of "b = 4". By stopping before that line of code has a chance to execute, the debugger gives you a chance to examine data or step into a function to see what's happening before what's happening before everything goes wrong.